# PHP Fatal error: A precedence rule was defined for > Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard

Tags: laravel

I've just finished updating an app from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2. Everything is working fine on my local Homestead install. When I deploy to my forge server, the process is failing with the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  A precedence rule was defined for
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard but this
>   method does not exist in
>   /home/forge/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php
>   on line 11

What could be causing this? I've tried running composer dump-autoload after the update, but still no luck.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting `/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php`. The files the error refers to were fine.

Comment: After I did this, I started getting an Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException'. I managed to fix this by editing my .env file so that any strings are contained within quotes. More info: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-log-does-not-exist?page=1

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` has a precedence statement to use `getGuard` from `AuthenticatesUsers` instead of from `RegistersUsers`.

The `AuthenticatesUsers` trait has a `getGuard` method defined in it.

Double check to make sure your version of that trait has the `getGuard` method and or double check those traits against the ones in the laravel repository.

Comment: My 'AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php' file (from within the vendor folder) accounts for this, I believe. It has:

  trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
  {
      use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
          AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
          AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard insteadof RegistersUsers;
      }
  }

There is no error on my Homestead setup though. Any other ideas? Thanks for the reply