# Laravel authentication error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and I've heard that the login and registration system is default in Laravel. However, I am not able to utilize it. I have placed login and register views inside the Auth directory within resources/views/.

**I have this controller in `Auth/AuthController.php`:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

   private $redirectTo = '/loginpage';

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
   }

   protected function validator(array $data)
   {
       return Validator::make($data, [
           'name' => 'required|max:255',
           'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
           'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
       ]);
   }

   protected function create(array $data)
   {
       return User::create([
           'name' => $data['name'],
           'email' => $data['email'],
           'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       ]);
   }
}
```

**The Routes are:**

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::controllers([
   'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

**But I am getting this error:**

> FatalErrorException in AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php line 11: A
>   precedence rule was defined for
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::getGuard but this
>   method does not exist

Comment: Did you check this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065996/php-fatal-error-a-precedence-rule-was-defined-for-illuminate-foundation-auth

Comment: there is no such file `compile.php` @Musterknabe

Comment: Can you try using this command in your CLI while being in your project directory? `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: similar error occured@Musterknabe

Comment: Sorry, no idea then.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://pastebin.com/YWisLuCt

Comment: @Dees040 that is  nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using larave 5.2 
Ssh into your directory then type

> php artisan make:auth

( this is to be done at the start of a project as it can overwrite some views). Also make sure you are connected to your db

Comment: can you try on a clean project and then compare with your files?