# FatalThrowableError Call to a member function attempt() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with my application. I haven't worked on it since 10 months.
Now I get a problem on the login form:

> FatalThrowableError
>
> Call to a member function attempt() on null

$this->auth doesn't seem to be initialized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065996/php-fatal-error-a-precedence-rule-was-defined-for-illuminate-foundation-auth

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't answer my question.